# What is this fitting called?

Tags: plumbing, pipe-fitting

I have a 1/2" female connector and need to know the name of the corresponding male fitting.   The female is one end of a 3' water supply line for a bathroom faucet.  I want to buy a 1/2" male fitting for it but I do not know what words to put into a search engine.  I plan to solder the male fitting onto a 1/2" copper pipe.

What name or words should I use to search?

[image: A fitting like this one.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the supply hose for a bathroom faucet is either [3/8" compression x 3/8"](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Fluidmaster-3-8-in-Compression-x-3-8-in-Compression-x-16-in-L-Braided-Stainless-Steel-Faucet-Connector-B6F16/203763902) or [3/8" compression x 1/2"](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Speakman-3-8-in-O-D-x-1-2-in-FIP-x-12-in-Stainless-Steel-Faucet-Connector-SPK-57572US/316963789) (with the 1/2" side connecting to the faucet).

I would assume that the fitting in your photo is a [1/2" copper sweat x 3/8" compression adaptor](https://www.homehardware.ca/en/12-copper-sweat-x-38-outside-diameter-compression-female-brass-connector/p/3236003):

[image]

If you have a hard time finding the above fitting (I couldn't find it on Amazon), here are some other options:

1. [1/2" Sweat x 3/8" Angled Compression Adaptor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09SZGHTL6) (The same as the above, but the ends are at 90° to each other)
2. [5/8" x 3/8" Compression Coupling](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BO7C3I)**
3. [5/8" x 3/8" Straight Compression Valve](https://5/8%20x%203/8%20compression%20valve)**
4. [1/2" SharkBite x 3/8" Compression Adaptor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YVYWJCY)
5. [1/2" Sweat x 3/8" Straight Valve](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09YCYLZ1J)
6. [1/2" Sweat x 1/2" NPT Female Adaptor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VLJPG7B) and  a [1/2" NPT Male x 3/8 Compression Adaptor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08FL9FJMR)

** 5/8" compression fittings fit 1/2" copper pipe.

Comment: Your link suggests searching on: 1/2" copper sweat x 3/8" compression

Comment: The OP mentions a 1/2" female connector - why do you suggest a 3/8" male connector to match?

Comment: Armand, I read the question as they needed the corresponding male connector to the female hose that they have. I suggested 3/8", which is typically the fitting size for connecting a sink's supply hose. I suggested compression, as that is typically the connection type for a sink's supply hose, and the treads in OP's photo look like compression threads.

Comment: @pdd I am looking for a female sweat fitting, with male threads, that I can solder onto 1/2" pipe that fits the 3/8" end of this water supply line:
https://www.amazon.com/Faucet-Bathroom-Kitchen-Connector-Braided/dp/B09PFYLBX5/ref=sr_1_5

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC, That is the fitting in my answer. One end is 1/2" female sweat copper and the other end is 3/8" compression (male threaded). You remove the nut that comes with it and connect the supply hose to it.